# How can I get the ID of the last inserted object in the MongoDB+SpringBoot

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I used SpringBoot REST API Microservices with MongoDB.
In the PUT Method, I am interested in update the latest score and add this score with its date to the history.
The Score Class:

```
    @Document(collection = "score")
public class Score {
    
    @NotBlank
    @JsonView(Views.class)
    private String player;
    @NotBlank
    @JsonView(Views.class)
    private String gamecode;
    @JsonView(Views.class)
    private Long score; 
    @JsonView(Views.class)
    private Date date;
    public ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> history;
    public String getPlayer() {
        return player;
    }
    public void setPlayer(String player) {
        this.player = player;
    }
    public String getGamecode() {
        return gamecode;
    }
    public void setGamecode(String gamecode) {
        this.gamecode = gamecode;
    }
    public Long getScore() {
        return score;
    }
    public void setScore(Long score) {
        this.score = score;
    }
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> getHistory() {
        return history;
    }
    public void setHistory(ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> history) {
        this.history = history;
    }
    
    
}
```

The Score Repository:

```
   @Repository
public interface ScoreRepository extends MongoRepository<Score, String>{
    List<Score> findByPlayerOrderByScoreDesc(String player);
}
```

The PUT Method:

```
//UPDATE SCORE
@PutMapping("/{player}")
public ResponseEntity<?> updateScore(@PathVariable("player")String player,
        @RequestBody @Valid  Score score){
    List<Score> s = repo.findByPlayerOrderByScoreDesc(player);
    if(s!=null) {
        map.put("score", score.getScore());
        map.put("date", score.getDate());
        s.get(0).history.add(map);
        repo.save(s.get(0));
        return ResponseEntity.ok(s);            
    } else {
        return ResponseEntity.status(400).body("Bad Request!");
    }
}
```

the problem is, when I save the new object, it does not replace my new version of an object with the old version and I have both of them, I cannot update.
So, I thought about getting the _id of the last inserted object and use this ID for updating but I do not know how can I do this.
Also, if you have other suggestions for solving this problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

## Update entry

You are not storing the element Id. So when you save it, since there is no Id, it makes a new entry.

If you want to update an existent entry you have to include its _id.
You can map MongoDB id by including the following in your `Score.class`.

```java
@Field("id") 
private String id;

public String getId() { return id; }
public void setId(String aId) { this.id= aId; }
```

## Set id

If you want to set an id to insert in your database you can just

```java
s.setId(score.getId() + player)
```

Bear in mind if you change the id of an entry it will insert a new one with the new id and keep the old entry untouched.

Comment: yes, I know. I do not want define id. MongoDB do this for me and is any way that i access to this id ?

Comment: What i tried to mean is that you have to add the ID property in your score class: `@Field("id") private String id` . In this way you will map mongo _id in your class. 
When you save it it will save under the same _id (update).

Comment: I do not want define Id, because in fact the player and gamecode are foreign keys for my database or if I want use something like id I am interested in to concatenate the player and gamecode to have primary key for Score

Comment: in fact I do not know how can i define concatenated id

Comment: Assuming that you added the field id as mentioned before, you can just use `s.setId(score.getId() + player)` to set the entry ID.

Comment: yes right, thank you.finally I decided to do this. but I was curious to find other solution.